Why tailwind classes are not supported on new laravel 11 / inertiajs site?
Reading docs at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation I try to add tailwindcss
into my new  laravel 11 / inertiajs 1.2 / vuejs 3 site I
and having in resources/views/app.blade.php :
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    @vite('resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css')
    @inertiaHead
</head>

in resources/css/app.css :
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

and in vite.config.js :

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

In tailwind.config.js I have :
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import forms from '@tailwindcss/forms';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [forms],
};

and in resources/js/app.js :
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

Not shure have I to run command :
npx tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/app.css  --watch

and in which command ? Have it valid params ? But anyway tailwind classes are not supported anyway...
    "php": "^8.2",
    "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^1.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^11.9",

and
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.4",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.8",
    "vite": "^5.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.1.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.36"
}

Thanks in advance!

did you install this with breeze? Tailwind is added by default in breeze

Do I did not install breeze. Not shure Do I need it with  inertiajs?

If you just started the project and you wish to use vuejs or react and connect them with inertiajs, then yeah it is easier since everything is preconfigured.

I have re read your question. You stated that this is still in the initial stage new laravel 11. If so, you can try and install it via starter kit https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/starter-kits

Do you think that installation with starter kit  is preferable ?

Preferrable that in a sense that basic functions are preconfigured for you. Choice with Inertia with React or Vue, or blade with alpine, plus auth, tailwind, etc. It all depends on you though. You could do everything on your own.

maybe a little late, but I think the following entries need to be added to tailwind.config.js to take all pages into account:
"./resources/**/*.js", "./resources/**/*.vue"
